# Objective C - Called object type 'BOOL' (aka 'bool') is not a function or function pointer

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, compiler-errors, boolean

Working on a legacy hybrid iOS project. Created one new Swift util class in ConsentManager.swift, like below,

```
import Foundation

public class ConsentManager: NSObject {
    @objc static let sharedInstance = ConsentManager()
    @objc private override init() {}
    @objc public func isDataPermissionConsentRequired() -> Bool
    {
        …
        return value; // based on logic
    }
}
```

Called the method from another objc class, ConsentChecker.m like,

```
@interface ConsentChecker ()
{
}
@end

@implementation ConsentChecker
-(void)checkConsent {
    
    // GETTING ERROR IN THE FOLLOWING LINE
    if (ConsentManager.sharedInstance.isDataPermissionConsentRequired())  { 
        …
    }
}
@end
```

Getting compiler error:

> Called object type 'BOOL' (aka 'bool') is not a function or function pointer

**Why and how to resolve it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're hitting this is that methods in Objective-C which take no arguments may be called implicitly using dot syntax *similar* to Swift's, but not exactly like it. A method declared like

```
// Inside of SomeClass
- (BOOL)someMethod { /* return something */ }
```

can be called either as

```
SomeClass *instance = ...

// Traditional Obj-C syntax:
BOOL value = [instance someMethod];
```

or

```
// Dot syntax accessor:
BOOL value = instance.someMethod;
```

Note that the dot syntax version does *not* use parentheses to denote the call. When you add parentheses like you would in Swift, Obj-C determines that you are trying to call the *returned* value from the method as if it were a function:

```
instance.someMethod();

// equivalent to:

BOOL value = [instance someMethod];
value(); // <- Called object type 'BOOL' (aka 'bool') is not a function or function pointer
```

You cannot call a `BOOL` like you can a function, hence the error.

@Dávid offers the more traditional Obj-C syntax for calling this method, but alternatively, you can simply drop the parentheses from your call:

```
if (ConsentManager.sharedInstance.isDataPermissionConsentRequired) {
```

---

Objective-C-ism note:

Dot syntax is most idiomatically used for method calls which appear like properties (e.g. boolean accessors like your `isDataPermissionConsentRequired`), even if the method might need to do a little bit of work to return that value (think: computed properties in Swift).

For methods which *perform* an action, or which return a value but might require a significant amount of work, traditional method call syntax is typically preferred:

```
// Prefer:
[instance doTheThing];
NSInteger result = [instance performSomeExpensiveCalculation];

// over:
instance.doTheThing;
NSInteger result = instance.performSomeExpensiveCalculation;
```

Answer (score 2):

The Obj-C syntax for executing methods is different from Swift's dot syntax.

This is the correct syntax:

```
if ([ConsentManager.sharedInstance isDataPermissionConsentRequired])  {
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want to call swift function on obj-c class you use to obj-c syntax

Correct Syntax is:

```
if ([ConsentManager.sharedInstance isDataPermissionConsentRequired])  {
    // Write logic here
}
```